# Cannot convert an image to another format using canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

### Problem

I'm trying to convert an image to another format using canvas, and then save the image to disk (using Node.js), I'm not sure why it's not working.

I don't really need the canvas itself, I'm just using it to convert an image. Should I append the canvas into an HTML element to make it work?

### Code

```
convertImage () {
    var image = new Image(); 
    image.src = 'C:/test/test.png';
    
    // Converts image to canvas
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    // Do I even need to draw it?
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    // Converts canvas to a data url
    var imageOut = new Image();
    let base64data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    imageOut.src = base64data;

    var data = base64data.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
    var buffer = new Buffer(data, 'base64');
    fs.writeFile('C:/test/converted.jpg', buffer);
}
```

Comment: Node.js does not have `Canvas` or `Image`.  Those are browser features.

Comment: @SLaks it's an Electron project (Chrome + node.js)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @SLaks there are no errors, it writes an image of 3 bytes in size to disk (so something is wrong there, not sure what)

Comment: You cannot access the filesystem from the browser. You will need to send the png data to your server

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto it's an electron project, I'm able to use node.js to access file system

Comment: Try `console.log(base64data)` and then put it into an `<img />` in your browser. Does it look like the proper image?

Comment: @samanime nope, it just outputs `data:,` that's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using canvas with nodejs may not be the best approach as it relies on the browser. Even though chromium should be able to handle it. In the past, I have relied on the jimp library

> An image processing library for Node written entirely in JavaScript, with zero native dependencies

https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp

here's what it would look like (not tested)

```
var Jimp = require("jimp");

convertImage (img, imgName) {
  Jimp.read(img, function (err, myImage) {
      if (err) throw err;
      myImage.quality(60)  // set JPEG quality
        .write(imgName);   // save
  });
}

convertImage('C:/test/test.png', 'C:/test/converted.jpg')
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good solution! I wish it also supported TIFF and GIF like canvas does though

Comment: I haven't tested those formats with jimp, but their commits suggest that support for both has been added

Answer (score 1):

Two issues with your code:

1. Images load asynchronously in the browser, so you need to wait for them to load before processing them (even when using Electron). In your case, the image was not loaded yet by the time you try to render it on the canvas, then the result was an empty .png
2. `writeFile` is also async in Node and not using a callback is deprecated. In your case you can use `fs.writeFileSync`

The suggested answer using jimp works fine, posting this for you and others wondering how to do the same without the abstraction of a library.

```
convertImage () {
    var image = new Image(); 
    image.onload = function() {
         // Converts image to canvas
         var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
         canvas.width = image.width;
         canvas.height = image.height;
         // Yes, you need to draw the canvas before creating an image from it
         canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0);

         // Converts canvas to a data url
         var imageOut = new Image();
         let base64data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
         imageOut.src = base64data;

         var data = base64data.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
         var buffer = new Buffer(data, 'base64');
         // use writeFileSync instead
         fs.writeFileSync('C:/test/converted.jpg', buffer);
    }
    image.src = 'C:/test/test.png';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, kind sir! It works!